# Implement classes Square and Triangle as subclasses of class Polygon

Tags: python

It will overload the constructor method init so it only takes one argument(side length) and will override method area that computes the area. I came up with this program, but it keeps saying "undefined name Polygon".

```
class Square(Polygon):
    'square class'

    def __init__(self, s):
        'constructor that initializes the side length of a square'
        Polygon.__init__(self, 4, s)

    def area(self):
        'returns square area'
        return self.s**2

from math import sqrt
class Triangle(Polygon):
    def __init__(self, s):
        'constructor that initializes the side length of an equilateral triangle'
        Polygon.__init__(self, 3, s)

    def area(self):
        'returns triangle area'
        return sqrt(3)*self.s**2/4
```

Comment: Did you define a ```Polygon``` class (before the other two)??

Comment: I dont understand. I'm still kind of new to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inherit from `Polygon`, you have to define it before you define the other classes that inherit from it.

```
class Polygon:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def area(self):
        raise NotImplemented

class Square(Polygon):
    'square class'

    def __init__(self, s):
        'constructor that initializes the side length of a square'
        Polygon.__init__(self, 4, s)

    def area(self):
        'returns square area'
        return self.s**2

from math import sqrt
class Triangle(Polygon):
    def __init__(self, s):
        'constructor that initializes the side length of an equilateral triangle'
        Polygon.__init__(self, 3, s)

    def area(self):
        'returns triangle area'
        return sqrt(3)*self.s**2/4
```